# I want to filter the JSON data based on checkbox clicked but it is working only when more than one checkbox is clicked

Tags: angularjs

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('checkBoxController', function ($scope) {

        //JSON data to be filtered based on last four properties
        $scope.patients=[{
        "id": 160,
        "email": "test.lnt.hillrom+StephenMurphy904@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Stephen",
        "lastName": "Murphy",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "zipcode": 55110,
        "address": "39 Xswhss lane ",
        "city": "White Bear Lake",
        "dob": "12/21/1947",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": null,
        "hillromId": "46399",
        "langKey": null,
        "middleName": null,
        "state": "MN",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "primaryPhone": null,
        "createdAt": 1490167354000,
        "isActivated": true,
        "adherence": 98,
        "lastTransmissionDate": "2017-03-20",
        "lastLoggedInAt": null,
        "clinics": [],
        "hcp": null,
        "clinicMRNId": {
        },
        "clinicNamesCSV": "Jeffrey,Cathy General Hospital",
        "hcpNamesCSV": null,
        "mrnId": null,
        "hoursOfUsage": 0.0,
        "serialNumber": null,
        "deviceType": "VEST",
        "expired": false,
        "isSettingsDeviated": false,
        "isHMRNonCompliant": true,
        "isMissedTherapy": false,
        "isNoEvent": false,
        "deviceTypeVest": true,
        "deviceTypeMonarch": false
    },
    {
        "id": 639,
        "email": "test.lnt.hillrom+ThomasPrice986@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Thomas",
        "lastName": "Price",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "zipcode": 54214,
        "address": "57 Emwzfe lane ",
        "city": null,
        "dob": "04/18/1955",
        "gender": null,
        "title": null,
        "hillromId": "22038",
        "langKey": null,
        "middleName": null,
        "state": null,
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "primaryPhone": null,
        "createdAt": 1490167354000,
        "isActivated": true,
        "adherence": 92,
        "lastTransmissionDate": "2017-03-20",
        "lastLoggedInAt": null,
        "clinics": [],
        "hcp": null,
        "clinicMRNId": {
        },
        "clinicNamesCSV": "Matthew,Cathy General Hospital",
        "hcpNamesCSV": null,
        "mrnId": null,
        "hoursOfUsage": 0.0,
        "serialNumber": null,
        "deviceType": "VEST",
        "expired": false,
        "isDeleted": false,
        "isSettingsDeviated": false,
        "isHMRNonCompliant": true,
        "isMissedTherapy": false,
        "isNoEvent": false,
        "deviceTypeVest": true,
        "deviceTypeMonarch": false
    },
    {
        "id": 43,
        "email": "test.lnt.hillrom+TimothyTaylor314@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Timothy",
        "lastName": "Taylor",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "zipcode": 92647,
        "address": "9 Jcktpp lane ",
        "city": null,
        "dob": "11/12/1930",
        "gender": null,
        "title": null,
        "hillromId": "10640",
        "langKey": null,
        "middleName": null,
        "state": null,
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "primaryPhone": null,
        "createdAt": 1490167354000,
        "isActivated": true,
        "adherence": 98,
        "lastTransmissionDate": "2017-03-20",
        "lastLoggedInAt": null,
        "clinics": [],
        "hcp": null,
        "clinicMRNId": {
        },
        "clinicNamesCSV": "Michelle,Cathy General Hospital",
        "hcpNamesCSV": null,
        "mrnId": null,
        "hoursOfUsage": 0.0,
        "serialNumber": null,
        "deviceType": "BOTH",
        "expired": false,
        "isSettingsDeviated": false,
        "isHMRNonCompliant": true,
        "isMissedTherapy": false,
        "isNoEvent": false,
        "deviceTypeVest": true,
        "deviceTypeMonarch": true
    },
    {
        "id": 642,
        "email": "test.lnt.hillrom+WilliamTorres381@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "William",
        "lastName": "Torres",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "zipcode": 68124,
        "address": "97 Qxqkcg park ",
        "city": null,
        "dob": "12/18/1953",
        "gender": null,
        "title": null,
        "hillromId": "56209",
        "langKey": null,
        "middleName": null,
        "state": null,
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "primaryPhone": null,
        "createdAt": 1490167354000,
        "isActivated": true,
        "adherence": 72,
        "lastTransmissionDate": "2017-03-20",
        "lastLoggedInAt": null,
        "clinics": [],
        "hcp": null,
        "clinicMRNId": {
        },
        "clinicNamesCSV": "Janet,Cathy General Hospital",
        "hcpNamesCSV": null,
        "mrnId": null,
        "hoursOfUsage": 0.0,
        "serialNumber": null,
        "deviceType": "MONARCH",
        "expired": false,
        "isSettingsDeviated": false,
        "isHMRNonCompliant": false,
        "isMissedTherapy": false,
        "isNoEvent": false,
        "deviceTypeVest": false,
        "deviceTypeMonarch": true
    },
    {
        "id": 92,
        "email": "test.lnt.hillrom+NancyWashington265@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Washington",
        "isDeleted": false,
        "zipcode": 55373,
        "address": "28 Huekni street ",
        "city": "Rockford",
        "dob": "02/16/1968",
        "gender": null,
        "title": null,
        "hillromId": "87291",
        "langKey": null,
        "middleName": null,
        "state": "MN",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "primaryPhone": null,
        "createdAt": 1490167354000,
        "isActivated": true,
        "adherence": 96,
        "lastTransmissionDate": "2017-03-19",
        "lastLoggedInAt": null,
        "clinics": [],
        "hcp": null,
        "clinicMRNId": {
        },
        "clinicNamesCSV": "Jeffrey,Cathy General Hospital",
        "hcpNamesCSV": null,
        "mrnId": null,
        "hoursOfUsage": 0.0,
        "serialNumber": null,
        "deviceType": "MONARCH",
        "expired": false,
        "isSettingsDeviated": false,
        "isHMRNonCompliant": false,
        "isMissedTherapy": true,
        "isNoEvent": false,
        "deviceTypeVest": true,
        "deviceTypeMonarch": true
    }];
    var init = function () {
    $scope.searchFilter = {};
    $scope.searchFilter.isHMRNonCompliant = false;
    $scope.searchFilter.isSettingsDeviated = false;
    $scope.searchFilter.isMissedTherapy = false;
    $scope.searchFilter.isNoEvent = false;
    $scope.searchFilter.deviceTypeVest = false;
    $scope.searchFilter.deviceTypeMonarch = false;
    };
    init();
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="checkBoxController">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">AngularJS - Retrieve Multiple Checkbox Selected Options</h3>


    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchFilter.isSettingsDeviated" />isSettingsDeviated
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchFilter.isHMRNonCompliant" />isHMRNonCompliant
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchFilter.isMissedTherapy" />isMissedTherapy
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchFilter.isNoEvent" />isNoEvent
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchFilter.deviceTypeVest" />deviceTypeVest
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchFilter.deviceTypeMonarch" />deviceTypeMonarch
                <p ng-repeat="patient in patients  | filter: { isNoEvent:searchFilter.isNoEvent,isSettingsDeviated:searchFilter.isSettingsDeviated,isMissedTherapy:searchFilter.isMissedTherapy,isHMRNonCompliant:searchFilter.isHMRNonCompliant,deviceTypeVest:searchFilter.deviceTypeVest,deviceTypeMonarch:searchFilter.deviceTypeMonarch }">{{patient.lastName}}, {{patient.firstName}}</p>

</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: Please see the below link : https://jsfiddle.net/shabreen/ro5funek/

Comment: Hi again, thank you for the updated code. It's working fine only when one checkbox is clicked but when more than one checkbox is clicked, the output is not coming as per the clicked checkboxes :(

Comment: Can you send me the expected result if isHMRNonCompliant and isNoevent is checked?

Comment: In that JSON data, there is no patient with both "isHMRNonCompliant" and "isNoevent" is true at the same time so the output when both are checked should show no data there.

Comment: Please take a look at this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ro5funek/4/. The problem was i was checking for OR condition.

Comment: thank u so much for the help :) it is perfectly working fine now, but I want to add two more checkboxes with labels "Active" and "Inactive". The requirement is initially when the page loads the checkbox with "Active label" will be checked by default and whole 5 patients will be listed and when "Inactive" is checked the data will disappear because all the patients in the JSON are in active state. "isDeleted" is the property in the JSON data which responds to Active and Inactive state. Condition will be like this : if isDeleted:false->Active=true;if isDeleted=true->inActive=false Plz hv a luk

Comment: you dont have top do anything. Just add two checkboxes. thats all. I wrote the filter considering that also. Please mark my aswer as ticked and do upvote :)

Comment: where is the fiddle?

Comment: This time you have to do it buddy. I have my own priorities. Try to solve on your own now. Its simple logic. And please do mark it as the answer.

Comment: thank u for the support :) it helped me a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to individually add different filters for the options you have provided. I have added a minimal version of your requirement in the fiddle. Please take a look at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ro5funek/3/). In HTML, you have to call like this.

```
<p ng-repeat="patient in patients  | isNoEvent:searchFilter.isNoEvent   | isSettingsDeviated:searchFilter.isSettingsDeviated ">{{patient.lastName}}, {{patient.firstName}}</p>
```

Comment: @Shabreen: Added fiddle example in answer

Comment: Please see the below code, I have added few more checkboxes but I am not getting output for that. https://jsfiddle.net/shabreen/4kj1qdr3/ Also, I have five person data in the JSON file but what you have sent is showing only 4 person's data. Let me know the solution please.

Comment: @Shabreen: I have updated the fiddle in my example. Please take a look. Do upvote if it helped. https://jsfiddle.net/ro5funek/3/

Comment: @Shabreen: https://jsfiddle.net/ro5funek/4/. Check the fiddle. If it helped do upvote and mark as answer